# What is the Name for the RAX Register?

Tags: assembly, architecture, x86-64

I know that EAX is essentially Extended AX register, but what is the RAX register called? My computer architecture professor was stumped, and I can't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: I'd say it's a return to the risc custom for using `r` for register. Notice x86-64 also added `r8`-`r15`.

Comment: I'm going to call them REXtended from now on

Comment: Ridiculous AX, the next generation (128 bit) will be ludicrous. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygE01sOhzz0 :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127668/what-does-the-r-in-x64-register-names-stand-for

The R as is turns out stands for 'Register'. I know a little unimaginative, and I would have preferred 'Ridiculous' myself.

Comment: hahaha.... ! I like it!